# What is the best way to process large arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a React JS app that uses an API to pull a JSON object that contains an array of 10,000+ objects. This array is then used to populate a table, with certain filters and options from checkboxes, dropdowns, that can manipulate the data. When tapping a checkbox, filter, sort, reduce functions are used on the array to return a specific subset of the array that can populate the table again.

There are 10-15 options to choose from, so 10-15 filter/map/reduce functions running on the data each time a box is checked.

These filtering options now cause a noticeable lag between clicking on the checkbox and changing the table. The app freezes while it calculates the new array. Is there a more efficient flow to filter my data?

Some example functions below below:

```
//gameData is an array of 10k+ objects
let inData = gameData

const options = {
    dateToTime: new Date('2020-03-01'),
    servers:[1,2,3],
    maps:['A','B','C']
}

function groupByArray(array, key) {
    return array.reduce(function (rv, x) {
        let v = key instanceof Function ? key(x) : x[key];
        let el = rv.find((r) => r && r.key === v);
        if (el) {
            el.values.push(x);
        } else {
            rv.push({ key: v, values: [x] });
        } return rv;
    }, []);
}

const gamesGrouped = groupByArray(inData, 'gameid')
inData = gamesGrouped.filter(a => a.playername != "new")
inData = inData.filter(game => {
    const thisTime = new Date(game.creationtime)
    return (thisTime < options.dateToTime)
})
inData = inData.filter(game => options.servers.includes(game.serverip))
inData.filter(game => options.maps.includes(game.map))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it is impossible to give general answer how to process array data, but I can give some pointers.

- be careful when nesting loops (to avoid repeating same iterations)
- avoid overheads, eg. find() can be replaced with for loop which is quite faster (I know it is easier to write find(), but you are looking at roughly 30% performance increase by switching it to for loop)
- paginate - you can process array in chunks using generators (eg. if you need to show only first 10 results, that would be faster then processing all of them)

*Also code that you provided is bit cryptic, you might want to use better naming.*

**Here is performance comparison** for groupByArray() function: https://jsbench.me/t7kltjm1sy/1

Worth noting, whenever I deal with performance sensitive situations I keep code to the VanillaJS as close as possible, because with large data sets even slight function overhead can be noticeable.